# Afnetworking return null json although its valid

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I wanted to parse json using Afnetworking but it returned null although the json is valid and working well here my code

```
 -(void)getData:(NSString *)serverName
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";




    [manager POST:serverName parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {





        [hud hide:YES];
        Category = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);

        // 3
        Category = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];


        [self.myCollectionView reloadData];



    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
        [hud hide:YES];

        // 3


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"خطأ في الاتصال" message:@"توجد مشكلة في الاتصال قم بالمحاولة مرة اخرى" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"اغلاق" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }];


}
```

but when i display the array on console it returns null
although when i displayed operation.responseString
it outputs the real json

```
[{"cat_name":"الكترونيات","cat_img":"الكترونيات.jpg"},{"cat_name":"arabiat","cat_img":"arabypic.jpg"}]
```

the output of responseObject is that

```
<efbbbf0d 0aefbbbf 5b7b2263 61745f6e 616d6522 3a22d8a7 d984d983 d8aad8b1 d988d986 d98ad8a7 d8aa222c 22636174 5f696d67 223a22d8 a7d984d9 83d8aad8 b1d988d9 86d98ad8 a7d8aa2e 6a706722 7d2c7b22 6361745f 6e616d65 223a2261 72616269 6174222c 22636174 5f696d67 223a2261 72616279 7069632e 6a706722 7d5d0a>
```

Comment: The success block is called, or failure? Any error?

Comment: the success block is called and when i output this NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);
it output that 
[{"cat_name":"الكترونيات","cat_img":"الكترونيات.jpg"},{"cat_name":"arabiat","cat_img":"arabypic.jpg"}]
but when i output the array  was null

Comment: You have checked operation.responseString but you call JSONObjectWithData for responseObject. Check responseObject (and add a result to your post) or just replace it with operation.responseString.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the managers response serializer to JSON so AFN will automatically decode the data. Once you've done that you don't need to use `NSJSONSerialization`, just use the `responseObject` which will be your array.

Comment: operation.responseString return real json but responseObject return that   
<efbbbf0d 0aefbbbf 5b7b2263 61745f6e 616d6522 3a22d8a7 d984d983 d8aad8b1 d988d986 d98ad8a7 d8aa222c 22636174 5f696d67 223a22d8 a7d984d9 83d8aad8 b1d988d9 86d98ad8 a7d8aa2e 6a706722 7d2c7b22 6361745f 6e616d65 223a2261 72616269 6174222c 22636174 5f696d67 223a2261 72616279 7069632e 6a706722 7d5d0a>

Comment: Looks like the raw data, because you use a basic serializer. Ask the JSON serialiser what the error is.